# .htaccess rewrite rule for photos

Tags: .htaccess, url-rewriting

i have url like this

```
http://www.example.com/photo?id=196
```

i want to change this to other URL. some thing like that.

```
http://www.example.com/test-article-by-me
```

"test article by me" is TITLE of the article and i want it to show in url.

can anybody guide me how ti achieve this ?
Waiting to hear from you guys.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can't do this using .htaccess alone as your .htaccess file has no knowledge of the relationship between the id & the title of a page

however, it *is* possible to set up your .htaccess to repoint

```
http://www.example.com/test-article-by-me
```

to

```
http://www.example.com/photo?title=test-article-by-me
```

with something like the following line in .htaccess

```
RewriteRule ^/([a-z0-9\-]*)$ /?title=$1
```

but your website's code will have to be set up to expect the `title` query string parameter rather than the `id` parameter